# Resources for learning about tetrad forms in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for a source to learn writing a metric in orthonormal form. I have read some books in general relativity like Sean Caroll's book but they were not so clear about this subject. Now I want to learn concepts and calculations in tetrad formalism and also I have read Wikipedia and it is not enough I think.

Comment: "Spinors and Space-time" Volume-I and chapter 7 from Volume-II by Penrose and Rindler is an excellent source for Newman-Penrose formalism.

Comment: "General Relativity (Second Edition)" of Norbert Straumann uses tetrad forms extensively.